# Uno Project: Making sure that a illegal plays return correctly?

Tags: java

I am writing a chunk of program to play Uno with other classes. My Uno project is almost finished, but I need to be sure that the part which checks to make sure that on moves after a Wild Card is played, I play either a legal card or return a -1. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class AlexaL_UnoPlayer implements UnoPlayer
{
public int play(List<Card> hand, Card upCard, Color calledColor, GameState state)
{
    int play = -1;
    boolean haveWild = false;
    boolean matchesWildCall = false;
    int indexOfWild = 0;
    //turn number of cards all players are holding into ints for later use
    int[] array = state.getNumCardsInHandsOfUpcomingPlayers();
    int playerNext = array[0];
    int playerTwoNext = array[1];
    int playerBefore = array[2];
    Color upCardColor = upCard.getColor();

    for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        //see if I have any wilds
        if(hand.get(i).getRank().equals(Rank.WILD) || hand.get(i).getRank().equals (Rank.WILD_D4))
        {
            haveWild = true;
            indexOfWild = i;
        }
        //set upCard color to calledColor if wild or wild_d4 are played
        if (upCard.getRank().equals(Rank.WILD) || upCard.getRank().equals(Rank.WILD_D4))
        {
            upCardColor = calledColor;
        }
        //always play a card matching rank of upCard, if possible, or play the first in hand which matches color
        if(hand.get(i).getColor().equals(upCardColor))
        {
            if(hand.get(i).getNumber() == upCard.getNumber())
            {
                play = i;
            }
        }

        //if cornered(no matching number or color), play a wild
        else if(haveWild == true)
        {
            play = indexOfWild;
        }

        //hold reverse cards until person next after me has less cards than person before me
        if(hand.get(i).getRank().equals(Rank.REVERSE) && playerNext < playerBefore)
        {
            play = i;
        }

        //play skips when person next to me has less cards than me
        if((hand.get(i).getRank().equals(Rank.SKIP) || hand.get(i).getRank().equals(Rank.DRAW_TWO)) && playerNext < hand.size())
        {
            play = i;
        }

    }
    return play;
}

public Color callColor(List<Card> hand)
{
    //strategy: change the color to the one i'm holding the most of
    Color changeTo = Color.GREEN;
    int numBlues = 0;
    int numGreens = 0;
    int numReds = 0;
    int numYellows = 0;
    //find out how many of each color i'm holding
    for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        if(hand.get(i).getColor().equals(Color.BLUE))
        {
            numBlues++;
        }
        else if(hand.get(i).getColor().equals(Color.RED))
        {
            numReds++;
        }
        else if(hand.get(i).getColor().equals(Color.GREEN))
        {
            numGreens++;
        }
        else if(hand.get(i).getColor().equals(Color.YELLOW))
        {
            numYellows++;
        }
    }
    //find out which i'm holding the most of and call that color
    //if no majority, return my favorite color(green)
    if(numBlues > numReds && numBlues > numGreens && numBlues > numYellows)
    {
        changeTo = Color.BLUE;
    }
    else if(numReds > numBlues && numReds > numGreens && numReds > numYellows)
    {
        changeTo = Color.RED;
    }
    else if(numGreens > numBlues && numGreens > numYellows && numGreens > numReds)
    {
        changeTo = Color.GREEN;
    }
    else if(numYellows > numBlues && numYellows > numGreens && numYellows > numReds)
    {
        changeTo = Color.YELLOW;
    }
    else 
    {
        changeTo = Color.GREEN;            
    }
    return changeTo;
}
}
```

For some reason, my output is telling me this:

```
You were given this hand:
  0. G7
  1. G5
  2. G+2
and the up card was: W
and the called color was: YELLOW
and you (wrongly) returned 2.
Valid plays would have included: -1
```

Can anyone provide some insight on why I am getting this error and how to fix it? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on just this code, it is hard to say what is wrong with your implementation.

Did you try step-by-step debugging of your play function?
Alternately, it would be beneficial to instrument your code with more trace statements to better figure out where the issue might be occurring.

For example:

Every where your play variable gets assigned a value, print its value to console with some context of where you are in code.

```
if(hand.get(i).getNumber() == upCard.getNumber())
{
    play = i;
    System.out.println("number match step: play = " + play ); // You can add such a line
}
```

This should give you an idea as to when play's value is getting mutated to 2 unexpectedly.

Just clutching at straws here, but what are the expected values of getColor and getNumber for wild cards.

In case you have them set to Green or 2 respectively, it might explain the output you are seeing because of the following fragment of code.

```
//always play a card matching rank of upCard, if possible, or play the first in hand      which matches color
        if(hand.get(i).getNumber() == upCard.getNumber())
        {
            play = i;
        }
        else if(hand.get(i).getColor() == upCardColor)
        {
            play = i;
        }
```

Comment: Edited after a little bit of changes.